# Downloaded Bitmap loses transparency when added to an ImageView

Tags: java, android, transparency, imageview

I am trying to show a potentially transparent image from a remote location, but the alpha channel seems to be colored white when I add it to my `ImageView`.

I am downloading a remote image with the following code:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) throws IOException {
   int bufferSize = 1024;
   InputStream in  = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(), bufferSize);
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

   try {
      in.close();
   } catch (Exception ignored) {

   }
   return bitmap;
}
```

In my `Activity` with the mentioned `ImageView` I have the following code (try-catch omitted):

```
if (bitmap != null) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

`bitmap.getConfig()` returns `ARGB_8888`.

I am coding against Android 1.6, i.e. SDK version 4.

Am I missing some magic setter? When I load the exact same picture as a `Drawable` from my res folder it works fine.

I noticed a setter called `setHasAlpha` on `Bitmap`, but this is since SDK level 12.

EDIT:
I tried getting the color of some of the pixels I know are transparent, and their color == `0`, which is transparent.

Comment: Are you sure this image is transparent? Did you try putting it in the drawable folder just to check if it the problem with setting the stream?

Comment: As I state in my question, I have tried it, and I am certain the picture has transparent areas.

Comment: Whats the [`Config`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) of your decoded bitmap? Use [`Bitmap.getConfig()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getConfig()) and make sure it's one that supports an alpha channel (should be ARGB_8888 by default, so just to make sure).

Comment: The bitmap config is `ARGB_8888`.

Comment: HI, did you solve this issue. I am facing as like same problem

Comment: Hey, look at the accepted answer below. Try setting a breakpoint inside the `setBackgroundColor` method.

Comment: after downloaded image i save in sdcard and also display in Image-view. Image view color red so that some picture background shows red and some white. white image means losing transparency that image and i am sure that all images has also transparency background.
Note: If i use wifi then all image display as like expected but when i use mobile data some picture shows white background and some shows red background.

Comment: Is there any issue in Image quality. Bitmap.getConfig() is ARGB_8888 check that is there any other issue. try bellow answer but not work.

Comment: Assuming your image is a PNG (or other implementation with transparency), your network type shouldn't be a factor. There are many application-specific things that could be a factor, you should post a separate question that has a concise code example that shows your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the ImageView itself has a background. Try setting the background color to transparent (eg, `imageView.setBackgroundColor(0);`

Comment: The background is transparent, as is the background of the parent layout.

Comment: I retract my statement, the backround got overwritten elsewhere. Sometimes the simplest things seem to be the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use compress format as PNG

```
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                fileOutputStream);
        bmpimg.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 20, bos);
```